# How to find source of TF_NAN_INPUT error

Tags: navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While using `amcl` and `move_base` I'm getting the following errors while applying a `tf_prefix`. It worked without the prefix but now that I'm using it, I get the following error:

```
remote[red1-0]: Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "robot_tf/odom" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (nan nan nan) (nan nan nan nan)
         at line 240 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-tf2-0.5.15/src/buffer_core.cpp
Error:   TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "robot_tf/odom" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (nan nan nan nan)
         at line 253 in /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-tf2-0.5.15/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

From the error listed above, what transform is being ignored? To the `robot_tf/odom` frame? What is the `authority` (I know that it says `"unknown_publisher"` but what is an `authority` in this context)?

At this point, I'm just trying to figure out how to read this error so that I can figure out where the issue lies. I know that `TF_NAN_INPUT` means that somewhere `NaN` values are being set in a transform and `TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION` means that somewhere a denormalized quaternion is being set.

In case it is useful, here is the error that `roswtf` reports:

```
ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/robot/laser_broadcaster_NGNeuromorphic1_18892_5059838883645381072] publishing transform [robot_tf/base_laser] with parent [robot_tf/base_link] already published by node [/robot/robot_tf/pioneer_transform_node_NGNeuromorphic1_18892_3963024023289368467]
 * node [/robot/robot_tf/pioneer_transform_node_NGNeuromorphic1_18892_3963024023289368467] publishing transform [robot_tf/base_laser] with parent [robot_tf/base_link] already published by node [/robot/laser_broadcaster_NGNeuromorphic1_18892_5059838883645381072]
```

and the output from `rqt_tf_tree`:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267361/how-to-find-source-of-tf_nan_input-error/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-25**:
I fixed the error that `roswtf` was reporting. I didn't realize that I was publishing the transform from `robot_tf/base_laser` -> `robot_tf/base_link` twice.

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-11-06**:
Can you more explain about this solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the error that `roswtf` was reporting. I didn't realize that I had two `tf` publishers publishing the transform from `robot_tf/base_laser` -> `robot_tf/base_link` twice.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-08-24**:
Hi @jayess I'm facing similar issue while running hector_mapping: https://answers.ros.org/question/360033/hector-mapping-tf-issue-tf_nan_input-and-tf_denormalized_quaternion/
There's only one publisher publishing base_link -> laser in my case as per best of my knowledge. What should I do? Thanks